# How can I change the dependencies of react project

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I am trying to reinstall an old project from react but am getting weird errors that I don't understand. I tried to change the version of react to newer but didn't work.
I am currently using npm 8.11.0 and node v16.15.1

[image]

Comment: Let's start with "which version of node and npm are you using" because that's missing from your post, but having said that: you update dependencies either by editing `package.json`, or by using the CLI to uninstall-and-save the current version and then explicitly installing-and-saving some other version.

Comment: `npm i -f` would fix it. If didn't, lower your node version.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans npm 8.11.0 and node v16.15.1

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how do i know what i have to update and to which version ?

Comment: @Amini i tried it but i go the following error: npm ERR! code E410
npm ERR! 410 Gone - GET https://npm.daypilot.org/daypilot-pro-react/expired/2019.3.4012.tar.gz

Comment: I don't have any clear answer but this might help you. Clear your npm cache. Upgrade your npm version. Change between node version using nvm.

Comment: You read the NPM log instead of just glossing over it: it's literally telling you which things have dependency collisions. And use `npm list` to see the full dependency tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is using the yarn tool, which helps to upgrade the dependencies to the correct version. (Important to delete first the node modules files.)